# How to pass Firebase UID using prepare for segue

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am using Swift and Firebase and I am trying to pass the UID in a prepare for segue. So when the user logs in and does something on the next view it will know it is him/her. However, when I do this I keep getting nil

This is the code that I have tried.

```
  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

if segue.identifier == "fromNewUserToAddCard" {

  if let destination = segue.destination as? AddCardViewController {

    destination.uid = tempUID
  }
 }
}
```

I have a property on the AddCardViewController of uid that tempUID is supposed to transfer to.

How can I fix this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you simply ask for FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid each time you want the user's uid? This is easier than handling the uid storage yourself